# slow mysql connection to server

Tags: mysql, yii

We use Yii v1.1.13 and mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32

We have 2 servers (server1, server2) using the same DB on server2.

When I send request from server2 using yiic

```
$list= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from foo')->queryAll();
```

download speed is about 140-200KB/s,

but when I run something like

```
Foo::model()->findAll();
```

download speed is about 10-20KB/s

What may cause it, may be smth wrong is with AR?

Answer (score 0):

Active Record will be much slower than a raw sql query.

There are things that you can do to speed it up like caching.

Also, the Foo::model() is more than just a mysql result set. It is a data model with much more information and much more versatile than a database table.

also, I havent used Yii so I may be wrong, but should you be doing `createcommand($sql)->queryall();`? Surely a comparative statement would be `createcommand($sql)->execute()`?